# LinearLayoutManager setOrientation after phone rotation not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying out the new `RecyclerView` in combination with the standard implementation of the `LayoutManager` the `LinearLayoutManager`. My goal is to let the `LayoutManager` draw my items horizontally when the device is in portrait orientation and draw them vertically when the device is in landscape. For this I use the following code in my activity's `onCreate`:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.nextColors);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext(), myData, myLayout);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
   linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
} else {
    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
}
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

This works fine if I start the activity while the device is in landscape or portrait mode. But when I change orientation in this activity the items are always drawn horizontally or vertically, depending on the device's orientation when the activity was first started. This doesn't make sense to me since after device rotation the activity is recreated and the `LayoutManager` should take the correct orientation.

Does anyone have an idea how to make `setOrientation` work with device orientation changes?

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to be able to diagnose your problem. Show the code you use to create your layout.

Comment: What do you mean? The adapter backing the RecyclerView?

Comment: @Squonk I've added more code about the recyclerview and it's adapter.

Comment: Can you check if the .orientation is correct when you rotate, so we know if it's a linear layout problem or a layoutmanager problem?

Comment: @sbaar The orientation value is correct after device rotation, the problem must be in the LinearLayoutManager

Comment: You can pass the orientation value in as part of the constructor for LinearLayoutManager.   This will set the initial orientation to that value.  You can do your checks as normal just new up the correct version when orientation changes. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#LinearLayoutManager(android.content.Context, int, boolean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting orientation before the saved state is restored in RecyclerView.

Try setting orientation on `Activity#onPostCreate` or `Activity#onResume` (in other words, after saved state is restored) so that saved state won't override your orientation value.

**Update**
As of version 21, LLM will not preserve orientation on configuration changes so your code should work as is. You don't need to care about saved state.

This change is made because saved state should be responsible to save variable state whereas orientation is a configuration which we can expect developer to set each time it is created.